# Sitecore: exporting all items of a given template everywhere on the site

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

As per title - I have a Template that spawns many items in many different places in the website; I would like to create a package containing all his instances without having to manually look for each of them individually.

I am using Sitecore 8.1. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "package containing all his instances" and "spawns many items in many different places"?

Comment: I mean that I want to create a package to export them, and I want to automatically add to the package all the Items of a specified template. By "spawns many items in many different places" I mean that several items of that template exist across the site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Package Designer, select the "Items Dynamically" option:

[image: Items Dynamically]

Then select the the root content item you wish to start from in the Content Tree. In the next screen, from the filters, select the templates you wish to filter by:

[image: Source Filter]

The package will contain all items with those filters.

Comment: Cheers - will try this tomorrow and come back.